# Add constraint in SQL Server to have same constraint name as just dropped

Tags: sql-server

I have this script to alter a constraint

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'RoleCategoryAssociation'
             AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PK_RoleCategoryAssociation')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleCategoryAssociation] 
        DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_RoleCategoryAssociation]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleCategoryAssociation] 
        ALTER COLUMN [RoleCategoryID] [INT] NULL

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoleCategoryAssociation] WITH CHECK 
        ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_RoleCategoryAssociation] 
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleID] ASC)
                        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
```

The `ADD CONSTRAINT` part always returns an error

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.RoleCategoryAssociation' and the index name 'PK_RoleCategoryAssociation'. The duplicate key value is (108).

How can I reuse that constraint name?

Comment: @DaleBurrell even if I try to only run the ADD CONSTRAINT part, it still shows an error. the `GO` does not fix this issue

Comment: @DaleBurrell the constraint is already drop since the drop constraint part works. then the add constraint shows an error. works for you but not for me

Comment: The error is because you're trying to add a primary key (unique) constraint on the table and there's a duplicate roleid... At least that's what it looks like to me. Was the constraint not on roleid before? Or was it a composite key maybe?

Comment: the constraint was roleid and rolecategoryid. I drop it to apply only to roleid

Comment: Well, that's the issue then. RoleID is not unique and a PK must be unique. You need to make your rows unique in some other way if you want to add a PK, I guess. Is there a reason you need to do this? Presumably this is a bridge table, so what's the point of having a bridge to a null column?

Comment: RoleCategoryID will be drop soon and I add a new column which is TagID

Comment: There's a few ways you can approach this, I guess. Perhaps you can just leave the primary key off the table until you add the TagID column then? If RoleID/TagID will be a unique combination, then you can make that the primary key once you've added the TagID column. You could still have a regular index on RoleID (and RoleCategoryID until it gets dropped altogether) if you need it for queries.

Comment: @ZLK I already add the tag ID but the existing records should have a NULL tag ID thats why i dont include first the TagID as the primary key

Comment: Right, I'm saying that if in the future the TagID is going to be non-null and is going to be a unique combination with RoleID, then when it's no longer nullable, you can add the primary key. Until then, leave the primary key off the table and maybe just use a regular (non-unique) index if you need it.

Comment: I now get it. thanks to both of you ZLK and Dale. My solution is just remove the primary key first, then i will create a migration script to populate the TagID value so I can add the primary key for RoleID and TagID. The error is correct, since there are existing records in RoleID that has duplicate value thats why I cant add the PK constraint on it.